# PhpThumb Errors

Tags: php, phpthumb

Trying to get phpthumb to work, but with a bit of issue at the moment. 
Got the simple demo to work, so I might be missing something on my function, but just can`t find what :(

The variables in this function have the following values:

> MYBB_ROOT=E:\wamp\www\mybb/
>   source_url=http://www.theblaze.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Screen-Shot-2013-04-29-at-7.41.26-AM.png
>   target_file=E:\wamp\www\mybb/images/topposts/thumbnails/thumb_13863.jpg
>   thumb_file_name=thumb_13863.jpg

```
function tp_createThumb($source_url,$target_file, $thumb_file_name){
    require_once MYBB_ROOT.'inc/plugins/topposts/phpthumb.class.php';
    require_once MYBB_ROOT.'inc/plugins/topposts/phpThumb.config.php';
    // create phpThumb object
    $phpThumb = new phpthumb();   
    //download file
    echo ("URL:".$source_url);
    downloadFile($source_url, MYBB_ROOT.'inc\\plugins\\topposts\temp\\'.$thumb_file_name);    
    // set data source -- do this first, any settings must be made AFTER this call    
    $phpThumb->setSourceData(MYBB_ROOT.'inc\\plugins\\topposts\temp\\'.$thumb_file_name);
    echo (' source:'.MYBB_ROOT.'inc\\plugins\\topposts\temp\\'.$thumb_file_name); 
    // PLEASE NOTE:
    // You must set any relevant config settings here. The phpThumb
    // object mode does NOT pull any settings from phpThumb.config.php
    // set parameters (see URL Parameters in phpthumb.readme.txt)
    $thumbnail_width = 100;
    $phpThumb->setParameter('w', $thumbnail_width);
    $phpThumb->setParameter('nohotlink_enabled', 'false');
    $phpThumb->setParameter('config_output_format', 'jpeg');
    $phpThumb->setParameter('zc', "C");
    $phpThumb->setParameter('config_allow_src_above_docroot', true);
    $phpThumb->setParameter('w', 200);
    $phpThumb->setParameter('h', 100);
    $phpThumb->setParameter('config_cache_disable_warning', true);
    $phpThumb->setParameter('config_imagemagick_path', null);
    $phpThumb->setParameter('config_prefer_imagemagick', false);
    // generate & output thumbnail
    if ($phpThumb->GenerateThumbnail()) { // this line is VERY important, do not remove it!
        if ($phpThumb->RenderToFile($output_filename)) {
            // do something on success
            echo 'Successfully rendered to "'.$output_filename.'"';
        } else {
            // do something with debug/error messages
            echo 'Failed bla:<pre>'.implode("\n\n", $phpThumb->debugmessages).'</pre>';
        }
        $phpThumb->purgeTempFiles();
    } else {
        // do something with debug/error messages
        echo '<form><textarea rows="25" cols="100" wrap="off">'.htmlentities(implode("\n* ", $phpThumb->debugmessages)).'</textarea></form><hr>';
    }
}
```

And here is the output error:

> phpThumb() v1.7.11-201108081537 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line
>   216
>   * setSourceData() setting $this->rawImageData (58 bytes; magic="E:\w" ( 0x45 0x3a 0x5c 0x77)) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 271
>   *                   file_exists() = 0 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1165
>   * file_exists_ignoreopenbasedir() = 0 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1166
>   *                       is_file() = 0 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1167
>   *                 is_executable() = 0 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1168
>   * ImageMagickThumbnailToGD() aborting because cannot find convert in $this->config_imagemagick_path (), and `which convert` returned () in
>   file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1198
>   * $AvailableImageOutputFormats = array(text;ico;wbmp;gif;png;jpeg) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 923
>   * $this->thumbnailFormat set to $this->config_output_format "jpeg" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 934
>   * $this->thumbnailQuality set to "75" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 951
>   * ResolveSource() exiting because $this->rawImageData is set (58 bytes) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 847
>   * setCacheDirectory() starting with config_cache_directory = "E:\wamp\www\mybb/inc\plugins\topposts\temp\" in file
>   "phpthumb.class.php" on line 958
>   * setting config_cache_directory to realpath(E:\wamp\www\mybb\inc\plugins\topposts\temp) =
>   "E:\wamp\www\mybb\inc\plugins\topposts\temp" in file
>   "phpthumb.class.php" on line 986
>   * SetCacheFilename() _raw set from md5($this->rawImageData) = "9fcad44eb8ae21004afb1addf5f08404" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on
>   line 3236
>   * SetCacheFilename() _par set from md5(_zcC_h100_w200_dpi150_q75) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3273
>   * starting ExtractEXIFgetImageSize() in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3035
>   * skipping GetImageSize() because $this->sourceFilename is empty in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3047
>   * bypassing EXIF and GetImageSize sections because $this->rawImageData is set, and $this->sourceFilename is not set, and source image is not
>   too large for GD (x=0MB) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3065
>   * SetOrientationDependantWidthHeight() starting with ""x"" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3014
>   * SetOrientationDependantWidthHeight() setting w="200", h="100" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3030
>   * exif_thumbnail() does not exist, cannot extract EXIF thumbnail in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3138
>   * EXIF thumbnail extraction: (size=0; type=""; 0x0) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3142
>   * starting SourceImageToGD() in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3400
>   * ImageCreateFromStringReplacement() calling built-in ImageCreateFromString() in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3956
>   * SourceImageToGD.ImageCreateFromStringReplacement() failed with unknown image type "E:\w" ( 0x45 0x3a 0x5c 0x77) in file
>   "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3443
>   * Not using EXIF thumbnail data because $this->exif_thumbnail_data is empty in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3471
>   * $this->gdimg_source is still empty in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3523
>   * ImageMagickThumbnailToGD() failed in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3525
>   * phpThumb() v1.7.11-201108081537 http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net
>
> Unknown image type identified by "E:\w" ( 0x45 0x3a 0x5c 0x77) in
>   SourceImageToGD() [3647] in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3847
>   * SourceImageToGD() failed in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 342

I`ve been over this for 5 hours (6am right now) and I just can't get it to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks
Eco

Answer (score 0):

managed to fix it. I think it was some issue with the relative paths.

Still this regexp I`m using here isn`t working all the time...

```
unction tp_createThumb($source_url,$target_file, $thumb_file_name){
    require_once MYBB_ROOT.'inc/plugins/topposts/phpthumb.class.php';
    require_once MYBB_ROOT.'inc/plugins/topposts/phpThumb.config.php';

    echo(" MYBB_ROOT=".MYBB_ROOT." source_url=".$source_url." target_file=".$target_file." thumb_file_name=".$thumb_file_name);
    // create phpThumb object
    $phpThumb = new phpthumb();


    //download file
    echo ("URL:".$source_url);
    downloadFile($source_url, MYBB_ROOT.'inc\\plugins\\topposts\temp\\'.$thumb_file_name);

    // set data source -- do this first, any settings must be made AFTER this call

    $phpThumb->setSourceData(file_get_contents(MYBB_ROOT.'inc/plugins/topposts/temp/'.$thumb_file_name));
    //$phpThumb->setSourceData(file_get_contents(MYBB_ROOT.'inc/plugins/topposts/temp/thumb_13863.jpg'));
    echo (' source:./topposts/temp/'.$thumb_file_name);

    // PLEASE NOTE:
    // You must set any relevant config settings here. The phpThumb
    // object mode does NOT pull any settings from phpThumb.config.php

    // set parameters (see URL Parameters in phpthumb.readme.txt)
    $thumbnail_width = 100;
    $phpThumb->setParameter('w', $thumbnail_width);
    $phpThumb->setParameter('nohotlink_enabled', 'false');
    $phpThumb->setParameter('config_output_format', 'jpeg');
    $phpThumb->setParameter('zc', "C");
    $phpThumb->setParameter('config_allow_src_above_docroot', true);
    $phpThumb->setParameter('w', 200);
    $phpThumb->setParameter('h', 100);
    $phpThumb->setParameter('config_cache_directory','./topposts/temp/');
    $phpThumb->setParameter('config_temp_directory', './topposts/temp/');
    $phpThumb->setParameter('config_cache_disable_warning', true);
    $phpThumb->setParameter('config_cache_disable_warning', true);
    $phpThumb->setParameter('config_imagemagick_path', null);
    $phpThumb->setParameter('config_prefer_imagemagick', false);



    // generate & output thumbnail
    if ($phpThumb->GenerateThumbnail()) { // this line is VERY important, do not remove it!
        if ($phpThumb->RenderToFile($target_file)) {
            // do something on success
            echo 'Successfully rendered to "'.$target_file.'"';
        } else {
            // do something with debug/error messages
            echo 'Failed bla:<pre>'.implode("\n\n", $phpThumb->debugmessages).'</pre>';
        }
        $phpThumb->purgeTempFiles();
    } else {
        // do something with debug/error messages
        echo '<form><textarea rows="55" cols="120" wrap="off">'.htmlentities(implode("\n* ", $phpThumb->debugmessages)).'</textarea></form><hr>';
    }
}
```